# Trying to to add a nested post with the ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have topics and posts and they both have relationships. I've been following the guide on how to add a nested post but when i try to reply to a post i get `Couldn't find Topic with 'id'=`.

In my `Posts` controller

```
def create
 @topic = Topic.find params[:topic_id]
 @post  = Post.new(post_params)
 @post.user_id = current_user.id
 @post.topic_id = @topic.id
 if @post.save
  redirect_to @topic
 else
  render :new
 end
end
```

In my `Topics` controller

```
def show
 @topic = Topic.find params[:id]
 @post = Post.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
 @posts = @topic.posts
 @topic.punch(request)
end
```

I'll keep it short for how i have my reply button in my topics/show.html.erb page

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <%= link_to "Reply", new_topic_post_path(@topic, :parent_id => post) %>
<% end %>
```

Now this is my form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@topic, @post] do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
 <%= f.input :content, as: :pagedown, input_html: { preview: true, rows: 10 }, label: 'Markdown' %>
 <%= f.submit "Post", class: 'button expanded' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It looks like `params[:topic_id]` is missing in `create`. Can you show us your routes files, the URL that `create` is under, and the parameters in the request?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I was missing `params[:topic_id]`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kristján Answered my question. I was missing `params[:topic_id]`